# Change organ registration in middle of piece in Logic Pro X

Tags: logic-pro

I'm using Logic Pro X 10.0.7. How can I change the registration of the pipe organ (i.e. the settings of the Church Organ plugin) in the middle of a piece?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the plugin settings are non-automatable, so I found a workaround: I created a summing track stack with the necessary registrations as subtracks, and I mute them when the corresponding registration is not selected (using automation). This way, I can even mix various registrations like organ stops (e.g. Principal + Flute) or use another instrument as a substitute for registrations not present in the Church Organ (e.g. Full Brass instead of reeds).